# How do I ensure 'Automatically follow redirects' setting is always disabled?

Tags: postman

I'm truing to verify that `301` redirects are configured correctly in my webapp. When I send a request I want to receive `301` response with new expected location header.

It appeared that instead of `301` I receive `200` because of the Postman setting 'Automatically follow redirects' which is enabled OOTB. Disabling the setting fixes my tests.

I'm just wondering how to store this configuration somewhere in the collection? I do not want any other dev (or CI?) to know that there is *some* setting in the Postman tool that needs to be changed. What if I work on two collections simultaneously where one requires the setting to be disabled and the other one is not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Newman, in your CI system, there is a setting for this that you can pass as an argument from the command line. `--ignore-redirects`.

https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman#newman-options

There are changes coming in to bring this down to the request level in the UI to make it more visible. Currently, there is not a programmatic way to do this in the Collection.

You could include this requirement in the Collection or Request Description, so others would know this needed to be disabled. Likewise, if this was a feature that you enabled without telling these external folks, how would they know that?

If it's something that you would like to see included in the app, you could create a feature request for it on the GH issue tracker repo, it's the only sure-fire way to tell the Postman Team, that this would be a cool feature to include.

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues